# How can I use .gif file in windowBackground in Android

Tags: android

I'm getting the white screen in android on the start of the app. So I'm showing some logo using windowBackground.

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_bg_loading</item>
  </style>
```

and splash_bg_loading file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I want to show .gif file instead of logo. is it possible? If yes How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can only add a static image in SplashScreen, you can't add gif or any animation in *android:windowBackground*.